# Radio Button in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, radiobuttonlist, groupname

I made a DataTemplate that will auto generate some questions (load from my dataview). Each question has four radio buttons, and I group all four buttons on  GroupName.

My problem is - if I have 2 or 3 questions, anytime I check a radio button on one question, the radio button on the question above will be unchecked. Anyone have solution for this?

Here is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itmCntrl" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Name="stk">
                <StackPanel Margin="5,2,0,0">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,10,10,5" Height="Auto">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="tbC"  FontSize="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Text="Question : "/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NOIDUNG}" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,5,10,5" Height="Auto">
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoA" GroupName="DA"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="A" Text="{Binding A}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoB" GroupName="DA" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="B" Text="{Binding B}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,5,10,5" Height="Auto">
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoC" GroupName="DA"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="C" Text="{Binding C}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoD" GroupName="DA" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="D" Text="{Binding D}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Only one radiobutton can be selected from on group. You should give different GroupNames to the different RadioButtons.

Comment: Yes I know, but this template will auto generate 4 radio buttons for any question it have, because of that, I can't hard set the different group name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`RadioButton.GroupName` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `DependencyProperty`, so that means that you can data bind unique values for each group:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Name="stk">
        <StackPanel Margin="5,2,0,0">
            <WrapPanel Margin="10,10,10,5" Height="Auto">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="tbC"  FontSize="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Text="Question : "/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NOIDUNG}" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel Margin="10,5,10,5" Height="Auto">
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdoA" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="A" Text="{Binding A}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdoB" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="B" Text="{Binding B}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel Margin="10,5,10,5" Height="Auto">
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdoC" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="C" Text="{Binding C}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdoD" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="D" Text="{Binding D}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

To make this example work, you would just need to add a `GroupName` property into the view model that you are data binding to in the `DataTemplate`, ie. the object that has the `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` properties in.

Comment: Thank you, but I add that obj to dataview which used by Items Control so that all item in data template can use, and I don't know how to binding that dataview to these radio Buttons
My code behind:
itmCntrl.ItemsSource = dvTHI;

Comment: I'll very appreciate if U could guide me more with your method, or can help me with the XAML problem I wrote under this :), thanks again

Comment: In *your* code example, you are data binding the `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` properties already. You just need to add a new property to the class that contains those properties and set it to a different name for each group of items.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way, because I bind the source Obj to my Itemcontrol, so I use this method:

```
<WrapPanel Margin="10,5,10,5" Height="Auto">
<RadioButton x:Name="rdoA" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=A}"/>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="A" Text="{Binding A}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rdoB" Margin="10,0,0,0" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=B}"/>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="B" Text="{Binding B}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
<TextBlock Text="&#xD;"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rdoC" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=C}"/>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="C" Text="{Binding C}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rdoD" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=D}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="D" Text="{Binding D}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

This works for me, but I have to group all 4 radio buttons on 1 WrapPanel, because If I split them in 2 panels, they will have their own groupname. But group 4 of them in 1 WrapPanel making they look so bad (1), cuz I want some thing like (2), not (1)

(2)
(the Question)

(A) (B)

(C) (D)

not

(1)

(the Question)

(A) (B) (C)

(D)

Anyway, tks for ur help :)